# F# XLinq traversal - curried version of function throws StackOverflowException

Tags: f#, linq-to-xml, currying

I have two similar functions `nested` and `nestedCurried` that traverse a XML tree with XLinq. They don't do anything useful - it's just a "shrinked" excerpt from a bit more complicated code.

What I'd expect from these two functions is to behave in the same fashion, as for me it looks like they are identical, with the only difference being the `nestedCurried` does not explicitly declare `e: XElement` argument - it's curied by the use of `elements` function and function composition `>>`

Meanwhile, the `nestedCurried` function throws `StackOverflowException` when called on any `XElement`

Evaluated in FSI:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
open System.Xml.Linq

let inline elements (e: XElement) = e.Elements() |> Seq.toList

let rec nested () e = elements e |> List.collect (nested ())
let rec nestedCurried () = elements >> List.collect (nestedCurried ())

let x = XDocument.Parse """<a></a>"""

let ok : XElement list = nested () (x.Root)
// Stack Overflow below
let boom : XElement list = nestedCurried () (x.Root)
```

Why does the `StackOverflowException` occur, what's the technical difference between those two functions, and how can I declare `nested` function without specifying the `XElement` argument explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look: every time you call `nestedCurried`, you call `nestedCurried` again, right away, unconditionally.

To make things a bit clearer, consider that the expression `List.collect f` is equivalent to `let x = f; List.collect x`. This means that your definition of `nestedCurried` is equivalent to this:

```
let nestedCurried () =
  let x = nestedCurried()
  elements >> List.collect x
```

Is it clearer now why this would cause infinite recursion?

Comment: ok I think I get it know, my initial thought was that these two functions are equivalent with regards to behavior - but they are not. Do I understand it correctly that if F# was lazily evaluated, then the exception would not occur?

Answer (score 1):

Your () parameter is not needed and is confusing things. You have partially applied elements with X.Root so you calling nestedCurried with X.Root over and over again - hence the Stack Overflow. To declare nested without specifying the argument explicitly you can do:

```
let nested = 
  let rec inner e = elements e |> List.collect (inner)
  inner
```

If you declared nestedCurried as

```
let rec nestedCurried = elements >> List.collect (nestedCurried)
```

You would have got a compiler error that "nestedCurried is evaluated as part of its own definition".

Comment: the () (`unit`) parameter denotes that some kind of argument can be passed to the function - to make things simpler I stripped the type of that argument to unit. Not sure I get why `nestedCurried` is being called with X.Root over and over again - shouldn't it rather be called with child elements? Why `nested` function does not loop in this case?

Comment: You already passing an argument to the function - e. In your definition you passing () and e. The () is doing nothing in this case except help you declare a function that causes a stack overflow :)